# How do I re-enable shadow in Lubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, lubuntu

Does anybody know how to re-enable shadow effects in Lubuntu 11.10??

It was enabled at first (without any extra tool), but somehow I managed to disable it. Unfortunately I can't remember how!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lubuntu doesn't have shadow effects by default. If you look at the Lubuntu website screenshots, none of them have shadow effects. Sorry.

If you do want shadows, you have a few options. The lightest weight option is to install xcompmgr. Here is the "how-to."

First, let's install xcompmgr. In the terminal, type:

```
sudo apt-get install xcompmgr
```

However, installing xcompmgr is useless unless you set it to autostart at login. This part is a bit trickier. The simple method is to create a .desktop file and place it in the directory `~/.config/autostart`. Hint: if you don't know how to show hidden files, simply press "[CONTROL]+h".

Copy-paste the following into the desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=xcompmgr
Name[en_US]=xcompmgr
Exec=xcompmgr -c -C -t-5 -l-5 -r4.2 -o.55 &
StartupNotify=true
```

When you're finished, your autostart directory should look similar to this:

[image: Autostart]

You might have other items or less items in this directory, but you should at least see the xcompmgr file.

One final note about shadows. You have a lot of options. I copied and pasted an example from the [Arch site](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xcompmgr#Configuration) for the 'Exec' part of the desktop file. Play around and find something that works for you. I found drop shadows really slowed down my system. It's all up to you!

Credit: [LubuntuTips](http://www.lubuntutips.com/2011/12/lubuntu-composite-manage-xcompmgr.html#.UFfasKSe7hU)